# Downloading a file from a server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am currently trying to download a file using Paramiko. I currently have the following code and am currently generating the following error, [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed. From what I've read, this error is associated with my hostname however I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
import os
import paramiko 
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='abc@de.ac.uk', username="hfseb", password="kjsvbkjcb")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
localpath = '/Users/abc/def'
remotepath = '/home/abc/def/game.log'
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Try giving port 22 in your connect call

Comment: It still gets the same error.

Comment: for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):   , this is the point the error is generated in the getaddrinfo function

Comment: Check the hostname again. Is it correct. have you put sftp:// also or not?\

Comment: The host name spelling is correct but I haven't put sftp://. I didn't know I had to. Does that go at the start of the name?

Comment: Yes. Try with that.

Comment: hmm, it still doesn't work

Comment: The problem is indeed with your hostname `abc@de.ac.uk` is not a proper host name. Likely you meant - the hostname as `de.ac.uk` and `abc` as a user. Simply using the hostname as `de.ac.uk` should fix this.

Comment: That's perfect thank you. Now I have another issue but lets see if I manage to work it out. On putty it requires it in that format so I assumed it was the same